# IIS 8.5 queuing certain request and not serving response

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8.5, worker-process

I am hosting ASP.NET web api application on IIS 8.5. The application is using .NET 4.5 framework. My application has multiple endpoints which serves data. Recently I have noticed, IIS queue up certain request (randomly) and any subsequent request to that endpoint is not served. I looked at worker process and can confirm lot of request are queued up.

1. What is the reason for this behavior?
2. Can this be due to some sort of memory leak?
3. What steps I can take to first identify the issue and then fix it ?
4. Can I use some tools to identify the issue?

the behavior is random, sometimes one endpoint is queued up sometime another endpoint is queued up.

please advise.

Comment: In my opinion, this is right behavior. If the IIS couldn't handle so many case in the same time , it will put the request in the queue. Could you please tell us the what you mean about multiple endpoint in web api? Do you mean multiple api controller or something else? Besides, I suggest you could check your thread workload in the IIS work process. It seems that your codes has a very big workload.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: by multiple endpoints I mean multiple controller having multiple `GET,PUT, POST & DELETE` calls. How can I check thread workload on IIS work process. Please share more details.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: the problem is queue never gets cleaned up. the behavior is inconsistent.

Comment: I guess this issue is related with your code. I suggest you could try to find out which API hangs or takes so long time. You could open the IIS management console and locate worker process as this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMiPg.png) shows. It will show which request takes so long time.